# Initialize Enum in extension complexType in an abstract class with xsd

Tags: c#, enums, xsd, initialization, abstract-class

```
<xs:simpleType name="Gender">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Male"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Female"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:complexType name="Client"
                abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="LastName"
                  type="xs:string"
                  use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="FirstName"
                  type="xs:string"
                  use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Gender"
                  type="Gender"
                  use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="MaleClient">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Client">
            <xs:attribute name="Gender"
                          type="Gender"
                          use="required"
                          fixed="Male"/>
            <xs:attribute name="NewMaleProperty"
                          type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="FemaleClient">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Client">
            <xs:attribute name="Gender"
                          type="Gender"
                          use="required"
                          fixed="Female"/>
            <xs:attribute name="NewFemaleProperty"
                          type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I have an abstract class (Client) and I extend that class in two subclasses (MaleClient and FemaleClient).
When I generate my classes using my current schema, a new property named "Gender1" is generated.
What i would like to do is initialize the MaleClient's and FemaleClient's gender to their respective values.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Your current definition is trying to combine a restriction (on the Gender attribute) and an extension (addition of a new attribute) in a single step.  Not only is this producing results you don't like in the binding tool, it makes the schema non-conformant.

What happens if you separate the two changes into two derivation steps?

```
<xs:complexType name="MaleClient-0">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:restriction base="Client">
      <xs:attribute name="Gender"
        type="Gender"
        use="required"
        fixed="Male"/>
    </xs:restriction>      
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="MaleClient">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="MaleClient-0">
      <xs:attribute name="NewMaleProperty"
        type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:extension>      
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

It would be nice to make the intermediate type anonymous, but that appears not to be possible (another flaw in the XSD surface syntax).

Comment: I tried that, MaleClient-0 was generated empty (no constructor, no properties) and thus not initializing the value to "Male".